# Iterating over array and change row based on element wise

Tags: python, numpy

If we have a 2D array. Suppose I would like to square the first item of a row and store it and then take the cube of the second item and store it as again in the original array. One way is to iterate over array:

```
#arr shape is (2,2)
arr = np.array([[1, 2], [4, 5]], np.int32)
squarred = np.zeros((arr.shape[0], 2))    
squarred [:,0] = arr[:,0]*arr[:,0]
squarred [:,1] = arr[:,1] * arr[:,1] * arr[:,1]
```

**Question**: Can we do the same thing using loop iteration please? This is a sample for 2D array. What if we have arbitrary array of any size and we would like to change each element in every row to a custom value, what would be you most efficient approach please?

**Edit**:

- 2D array of size (2,2) and same for output. But the output element have the first element of each row squared and the second cubed. In general, what would be the most efficient way to do it given we have even larger arrays please?
- Can you please post your answer for a element-wise change of each value in each row to arbitrary value please?

Comment: Please add input and expected output

Comment: `arr ** [2,3]`. But that's without a loop.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny. Thank you. What would be the most efficient way based on what you know please? What if we have more than 2 elements per row where we want to do a custom change on each element, what would be your approach please?

Comment: @Avra - Broadcasting should be the fastest method regardless of the size of your array. Iterating in a loop should be the slowest by far. If you have a different question, please ask in another question on stackoverflow.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny. Thank you. So can you please post your answer for a element-wise change of each value in each row to arbitrary value please?

Comment: @Avra - Sorry, I can't post an answer to a different question than your example. And you specifically ask for a loop solution. I won't post an answer with a loop for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.power`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.power.html) function:

```
# 1xN could also be [3, 5], [2, 8], or any array of size N
exponents_per_row = np.arange(2, 4)
exponents = np.tile(exponents_per_row, (2, 1))
res = np.power(arr, exponents)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[[  1   8]
 [ 16 125]]
```

Comment: Thank you. For arbitrary change of each item in a row to a custom power, can you please change code accordingly?

Comment: @Avra I don't understand the question, just change the exponents array as you see fit

Comment: I mean, if we have `N` elements in each row in `NxM` array, so we would like to change each element in the row of size `1xN` to arbitrary value and same for all other rows, what would be your approach here please?

Comment: @Avra updated the answer!

Comment: Thanks! So the exponents will be applied to each row, what if changes made to each row has different exponents than other rows please? I mean, each row would have its own exponents. Should we in this case use a loop please? If yes, is it done like this `for x in Arr: exponents_per_row = np.arange(2, 4)
exponents = np.tile(exponents_per_row, (2, 1))
res = np.power(arr, exponents)
print(res)`